# How to check if text is visible on web page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How does one check if this  text (see picture) is visible to the user on the web page?

.is_displayed() clearly always returns true. Any alternatives?

The following always returns true (even when the text is not visible to the user)

`driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".has-primary-color.has-text-color").is_displayed()`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To probe if the text within *`<h3>`*  tag is visible to the user on the web page or not you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3.has-primary-color.has-text-color")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h3[@class='has-primary-color has-text-color']")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you! I can't get either of the locator straties working. Also could you provide a locator strategy for checking if a specific text string is visible instead? 

Because there are multiple text strings using that class.

Comment: _visible to the user on the web page_ -> `visibility_of_element_located()`